# Arangodb createDocumentRaw throwing back Null pointer exception

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to create a document in my collection using the arangodb driver (2.7.2) and using the createDocumentRaw method, however it always throws a null pointer with the below stack reference.

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     com.arangodb.impl.InternalDocumentDriverImpl._createDocument(InternalDocumentDriverImpl.java:73)
>     com.arangodb.impl.InternalDocumentDriverImpl.createDocumentRaw(InternalDocumentDriverImpl.java:106)

Below is my arango db configuration setup.

```
this.configure  = new ArangoConfigure();
        ArangoHost arangohost = new ArangoHost("127.0.0.1", 8529);
        this.configure.setArangoHost(arangohost);
        this.configure.setDefaultDatabase("ProvenanceNewGraph");
        this.driver = new ArangoDriver(configure);
```

and my post to arango :

```
DocumentEntity<String> entity = this.driver.createDocumentRaw("myCollection", myJSON.toString(), Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.FALSE);
```

Am i missing something which should be present?

Comment: hi Sorry all, please ignore this question i realised i was being silly had not called the configure.init() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just for the benefit , i wanted to answer my above question, I hadn't called the congifure.init() method and hence it was throwing the exception...